# how can I enable my form to use ajax in ruby on rails using haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to create a form to send data via ajax and order to update a user (I used scaffolds, so the methods for update already exist).

I created my form and I did something like this

```
%form{ :action => "/users/customsave", :method => "post", :controller => "/users", :remote=>"true"}
```

according what I read with saying `:remote => true` would do it with ajax, the problem is that doesnt work and the worst part is that kills my session for some weird reason after I submit the post.

Any idea how to do this? submit with ajax?

Thanks

Comment: You should use the FormHelpers instead of raw HTML forms (or HAML).

Comment: I would like to use them, but this was already started, and I am kinda new with rails, but very new with haml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
%form{ :action => "/users/customsave", :method => "post", :controller => "/users", data: {remote: true}}
```

You can use

```
= form_for 'model', url: "/users/customsave", method: :post, data: { remote: true } do |f|
  = f.text_field 'field_name'
  / generates <input type="text" name="model[field_name]" 
    id="model_field_name"
    value="value of the field in case you don't specify string, 
    instead an actual model">
```

Comment: please, do you know what I have to do in case I want to make it form_for ?

Comment: thank you a lot! but, is it possible to  use the default edit method of the scaffolds? basically what I want to do its just show a form to update the info but on ajax way :s and if I specify a value in an input here I just dont see printed, any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your form like so:

```
= form_tag({:controller => "users", :action => "customsave"}, :remote => true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the form helpers, as @MrYoshiji told in his comment, for example, [form_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag)

However, if you still wants to use HAML, you need to use `data-remote`:

```
%form{ :action => "/users/customsave", :method => "post", :controller => "/users", 'data-remote'=>"true"}
```

But beware, because this is not the expected interface and might change in the future, causing an expansive upgrade from your side.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to use `form_for` or `form_tag`, `%form` creates an html form like so:

```
= form_tag({:controller => "users", :action => "customsave"}, :remote => true)
```

Second, make sure you actually create a customsave.js.erb js view to handle the response of the ajax request.